# Console.log error: React Form "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" even though it's working in submitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't get why I got this error in my console even though the form was working in submitting the data to the list.

> Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

I created a React app in which there is a list of boxes with data and I click on the "Add" button. The add form adds another box with data to the list. I looked online for suggestions but couldn't find anything that can help me. Do I ignore the error or fix it?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FormField from './FormFieldBox';
import { CountryDropdown } from 'react-country-region-selector';

function validate(name, isin, country) {
  // true means invalid, so our conditions got reversed
  return {
    name: name.length === 0,
    isin: isin.length === 0,
    country: country === ""
  };
}

export default class PopupForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      isin: '',
      country: ''
    }
  }

  selectCountry = (e) => {
    this.setState({ country: e });
  }

  updateInput = (e) =>{
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  closePopupSubmit = (e) => {
    if (!this.canBeSubmitted()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    let security = {     //1.gather security data from form submit
      name: this.state.name,
      isin: this.state.isin,
      country: this.state.country
     } 
     this.props.submitPopup(security); //2.closePopup function, add security data
  }
  canBeSubmitted() {
    const errors = validate(this.state.name, this.state.isin, this.state.country);
    const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
    return !isDisabled;
  }

  cancelPopupSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
     this.props.cancelPopup();
  }

  render() {
    const errors = validate(this.state.name, this.state.isin, this.state.country);
    const isDisabled = Object.keys(errors).some(x => errors[x]);
    return (
      <div className='popup'>  
      <div className='popup-inner'>  
      <form onSubmit={this.closePopupSubmit} className="add-form">
        <h2>Add Security</h2>
        <div className="form-input">
        <FormField onChange={this.updateInput} className={errors.name ? "input error" : "input"} label="Name" type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} />
        <FormField onChange={this.updateInput} className={errors.isin ? "input error" : "input"} label="ISIN" type="text" name="isin" value={this.state.isin} />
        <div className="field">
          <label className="label">Country</label>
          <div className="control">
            <CountryDropdown onChange={this.selectCountry} className={errors.country ? "input error" : "input"} value={this.state.country} />
            {Boolean(this.state.country !== "") || (
            <div className="err-msg">
              Please select the country
            </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="buttons-box">
          <button type="button" onClick={this.cancelPopupSubmit} className="button">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" className="button" disabled={isDisabled}>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>  
      </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This warning is letting you know the form submission is aborting because you're either trying to submit while navigating away from the page or the form is being removed from the DOM while still submitting. That said, I can help track down the issue if you create a simple **working** stripped down version of the code above using a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) -- please share the link to the codesandbox when done.

Comment: HI. I'm new to Codesandbox but I tried to add files that's similar to my react app. https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-leakey-hkylo

Comment: My guess is that since the form is within a modal that you may be removing it from the DOM before the submission to your backend has compeleted. That said, I'm going to simplify your current code and see if I can refactor it to avoid this behavior.

Comment: I don't really have a backend. I've been working on this for a job interview and the instructions they left for me included "The application should be done completely on the client side (no back end required), with adding/editing/deleting of securities and prices saved on the front-end in JavaScript objects." So I just created `securities.json` to display the data and add to it...

Comment: No problem. I still think the problem lies within how the form is being submitted and removed from the DOM. Give a few minutes and I'll come back with a refactored codesandbox. You can plug it into your local repo and if the issue still persists, then I can take a look at your entire repo.

Comment: Thank you so much! Anyway, I already finished adding part and am now working on the editing part. I'm looking at this tutorial for help: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/handling-user-input-in-react-crud-1396e51a70bf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when you wrapped `e.preventDefault()` in a conditional on your form submission that this is the root cause of the problem; as it prevents default actions -- in this case, the default action is to prevent a page refresh -- from firing (which is what we **always** want when working with React!).

That said, I've refactored your code to be less WET (**W**rite **E**verything **T**wice) and made your components reusable and more flexible. There are some detailed notes that you can read to help understand the flow and my decision making. Since this is for a job interview, if you really want to impress, start writing tests for your components -- not only will they work, but they'll be backed by tests that prove they work (or break, if the codebase changes)!

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

**Working example:** (includes form validation, adding an item to a list and editing an item in place from a list)

[image: Edit Add and Remove Fields]

---

On a side note, I'd avoid free tutorials as they're usually old/unmaintained, filled with syntax mistakes, and preach bad habits. If you're serious about web development, I'd highly recommend investing in some paid tutorials (like this [one](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-2nd-edition/) -- usually on sale for ~$10) as they're from industry professionals, maintained by the teacher or TAs, and tend to go more in depth about how stuff works.

Comment: I have this tutorial that you mentioned at Udemy. I haven't started on it yet. I'll start the course after I submit the project for the job interview tomorrow. Right now, I'm reviewing your edits and am very impressed. I actually started to learn about React in October 2019 and considered myself as a beginner/intermediate in React.  Can I contact you with more questions in the future? Anyway, I'll finish reviewing your edits and merge it with my code and then add the deleting code to delete the box.

Comment: Absolutely, contact me anytime, I'll do my best to answer any future Q's (time permitting). That's great, I definitely recommend starting on that tutorial afterward -- you'll benefit greatly from it. There are a few more things I'd like to add (like creating a reusable modal, creating tests and prop type checking), but I wanted to keep it clean and easy to understand; however these are still worth consdering/adding into your submission if you have the time.